# Share software from one system to another using PHP

Tags: php, ip, system, exe

I have installed a window executable software in my linux machine(local not in the web server). I need to share that .exe file to other system using IP address. Can it be done with PHP?

Comment: when your "webserver" can reach the exe-file you are able to share it for download, but you can't exexute the programm through web

Comment: If not possible with php,Is there any option to do it? I think, web server should not play a role in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Assuming you got LAMP installed.

You can just put your file in a folder inside apache root folder (usually `/www`).

`/www/sharedfiles/yourfile.exe`

You can then access your file in other computer using your IP address **in a browser**:

`yourip/sharedfiles/yourfile.exe`

Comment: Yeah, it's easier than setting up Samba. I'm still using it when my flashdisk is missing.

Comment: I copied .exe file into the www folder but not installed in the local system. When I try as you suggested,it says "You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server."

Comment: Usually I just `sudo chmod -R 777` the `sharedfiles` folder. That's why I suggest you put it inside a folder, so you don't mess up with other folder permission.

Comment: I have php program which will run exe file But the issue is through command prompt php program able to run exe file but in the web server it doesn't work

Comment: Hmm, don't know what's the real problem here. Hosted web server? It may conflict with the policy.